# ImageBuilder.Current.DecodeStream() doesn't resize

Tags: imageresizer

I'm passing a memory stream to the ImageBuilder.Current.DecodeStream() method, with some resize settings, but it's not resizing the resulting bitmap.

var bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image.FixBase64ForImage());
var streamBitmap = new MemoryStream(bitmapData);
var bitImage = ImageBuilder.Current.DecodeStream(streamBitmap, settings, "");

`FixBase64ForImage()` is just an extension method I wrote to remove the data:image/jpg;;base64, from the submitted base64 encoded photo.

I pass a 640x640 square photo to the `ImageBuilder.Current.DecodeStream()` method, and pass it settings that looks like this

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings(string.Format("maxwidth={0}&maxheight={1}&format={2}&crop={3}&quality={4}", maxwidth, maxheight,format, crop, quality));
```

No matter what max width/height I pass it, it always returns the full 640x640 photo (and seems like there is no quality compression as well).

This leads me to believe the resize settings are simply ignored. Is there another way to accomplish the same thing, or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageBuilder.Current.DecodeStream does not do any image processing; it is only for decoding an image stream into an image bitmap. It is called by .LoadImage(), among others.

Use the .Build() overloads to perform image processing.

Comment: Curious why it has the resize settings in the method... Oh well, `.Build()` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Several commands affect how an image is decoded (Is color profile information considered? Which decoder should we use?)